# How does one say "carefree" in German?

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german

According to [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=carefree), there are three similar ways to say it: *sorglos*, *sorgenlos* and *sorgenfrei*. This doesn't include the other translations such as *unbekümmert* or *unbeschwert*, either! Then which one would I use, and what are the difference(s) between them?

Also, another question that someone could possibly answer: if I am met with multiple translations for one word like this, which one should I use? Sometimes I just choose one randomly, and a German speaker tells me that the sentence I am making sounds really strange, unlike one a native speaker would make.

As a commenter mentioned, here is the sentence I would like to translate:

> The children smiled and looked happy and carefree.

Answer (score 4):

It depends in what context the word is mentioned.
An example:

> She has a carefree attitude toward life.
>   *Sie hat eine unbeschwerte/unbekümmerte/sorglose/sorgenfreie Einstellung zum Leben.*

The translations can all be used here but have a slightly different meaning.

Your example:

> The children smiled and looked happy and carefree.
>   Die Kinder lachten und wirkten sorglos und glücklich.

If it is used as a single word in e.g. insurance advertisements it could also be translated as "*rundum sorglos Paket*" but this would be a special occurrence.

According to [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sorglos%2Cunbeschwert%2Csorgenfrei%2Cunbek%C3%BCmmert&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csorglos%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunbeschwert%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csorgenfrei%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunbek%C3%BCmmert%3B%2Cc0) "*unbekümmert*" still seems to be the most used adjective of the four given but in most cases all of them can be used with a slightly different meaning. If it sounds strange it does not mean it is wrong.

[image: ngram: usage of unbeschwert, sorglos, sorgenfrei, unbekümmert over time]

> "*unbekümmert/unbeschwert*"

is used when you want to express that you do not feel grief about something.

> "*sorglos/sorgenfrei*"

is more likely used when you want to express that you are not afraid of something.

Comment: Unbeschwerte und unbekümmerte und sorgenfrei bedeuten nicht dasselbe! Ich kann Probleme ("Sorgen") haben und trotzdem naiv unbekümmert sein.